# How can I make a cloned element work separately from its parent?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, function, clone

I have a button that when clicked calls a function that randomizes a number inside of it. Then I have another button that when it's clicked it clones the first button.

[image]

What I want to do is to turn the cloned button independent from the original (while using the same function), but when it's clicked, instead of calling the function and randomizing its own number, it randomizes it's parent's. How can I make this work? I'm using jQuery.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('body').on('click', '#button1', function() {
    document.querySelector('#num1').textContent = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
  });

  $('#clone1').on('click', function() {
    console.log("lolo");
    const place = $('#place');
    $('#block1').clone().appendTo(place);
  });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="section1">
    <div class="block" id="block1">
      <button class="button" id="button1">
        <div class="num" id="num1">1</div>
      </button>
    </div>

    <div class="section2">
      <button class="clone1" id="clone1">clone1</button>
      <div class="place" id="place">

      </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because the button to be edited was being selected by the id:

```
document.querySelector('#num1').textContent = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
```

Instead, have the handler edit the event target:

```
$('body').on('click', '#button1', function(event) {
  event.target.textContent = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('body').on('click', '#button1', function(event) {
   event.currentTarget.querySelector('.num').textContent = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
  });

  $('#clone1').on('click', function() {
    console.log("lolo");
    const place = $('#place');
    $('#block1').clone().appendTo(place);
  });

});
```

```css
.face {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="section1">
    <div class="block" id="block1">
      <button class="button" id="button1">
        <div class="num" id="num1">1</div>
        <div class="face"></div>
      </button>
    </div>

    <div class="section2">
      <button class="clone1" id="clone1">clone1</button>
      <div class="place" id="place">

      </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That worked, thank you so much! But I have another question. What if there was more text inside the button, like under (<div class="num" id="num1">1</div>), what can I do to only change the especific "num1" text?

Comment: Anytime! For that, first we need to use `currentTarget` instead of `target` to avoid issues with event bubbling and capture. `currentTarget` is the element that the handler is added to, in this case, the button itself. Then we can run a query selector on the button to select the element we want to edit. I updated my answer. (note I used the snippet's Jquery because it loaded a bit faster)

Comment: If we didn't use `currentTarget` and used `target` instead, if we click on the emoji, the handler will edit the emoji because it's the `target`

Answer (score 1):

Don't use IDs, which are supposed to be unique, use classes.

Then the event handler can use `$(this)` to find the element with the class inside the button.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('body').on('click', '.button1', function() {
    $(this).find(".num1").text(Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1));
  });

  $('#clone1').on('click', function() {
    console.log("lolo");
    const place = $('#place');
    $('#block1').clone().appendTo(place);
  });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="section1">
    <div class="block" id="block1">
      <button class="button button1" id="button1">
        <div class="num num1">1</div>
      </button>
    </div>

    <div class="section2">
      <button class="clone1" id="clone1">clone1</button>
      <div class="place" id="place">

      </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That worked exactly as I needed! But I have another question. Is there any way to make the clone be a clone of the unaltered first button? Because once the original button is clicked, the clone inherit the num1 value.

Comment: You can copy the original button's HTML instead of cloning it.

Comment: `clone = $("<div>").html($("#block1").html))`